# Apollo Network request failed only in android simulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting a Network request failed only on android simulator.

```
ApolloError: Network request failed
    at new ApolloError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=myapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:162987:26)
    at Object.error (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app= myapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:140360:70)
    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app= myapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:158462:20)
```

It works fine on iOS and iOS simulator.

The call is a real production server and not one hosted on my machine.

Already tried setting up `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest.
Also whitelisted my domain in a `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://myserverdomain.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

what am I missing here ?

Comment: A simple fetch works, so it seems it's a problem with Apollo config

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

First thing to know, if using Axios, it adds headers to the request.
Also, my android .env variable where was stored the url didn't work.